# display: none/block onclick messes up

Tags: javascript

I am having troubles for some reason, and I can't seem to find out how...
I am making a quiz, which starts with a start button, and has buttons "next" and "prev" buttons.. When I hit the start button, the question 1 and answer 1 will come up and the start button disappears, when I then hit next it is loading in the second question, but not the answer 2

my code:

```
// Hide / Show actions
function hideStartButton() { document.getElementById("start-button").style.display = "none";}
function showAnswers1() { document.getElementById("answers1").style.display = "block"; }
function hideAnswers1() { document.getElementById("answers1").style.display = "none";  }
function showAnswers2() { document.getElementById("answers2").style.display = "block"; }
function hideAnswers2() { document.getElementById("answers2").style.display = "none";  }
```

**Complete code:** http://jsfiddle.net/5jz092cb/

it does load answers2 when I don't use hideAnswer1(); else it comes up blank?

Comment: Updated my answer...seems you need to loop through the `document.getElementById('answers')` element hiding everything *unless* it matches the answer/element you want, *then* display that element instead.

Comment: yes but that would require me actually hide and show it and thats not working properly...

Answer (score 1):

**CSS**

```
.hidden {display: none;}
```

**JavaScript**

```
change('answers1','hidden');
change(document.getElementById('answers1'),'hidden');
//etc.

function change(id,c)
{
 if (id_(id)) {id_(id).className = c; if (id_(id).className=='') {id_(id).removeAttribute('class');}}
 else if (id) {id.className = c; if (id.className=='') {id.removeAttribute('class');}}
 else {alert('Error: the class id \''+id+'\' was not found or has not yet been imported to the DOM.\n\nNew class intended: '+c);}
}
```

**Also** you need to hide *and* show layers *simultaneously* often in these kind of scenarios so you may very well need to do something like *loop* through and hide all the elements *except* the one you want to hide.